# How do I show a PDF file on a web page and detect scrolling?

Tags: pdf

I need to allow users to upload PDF documents that other users will read. That isn't that big of a deal, but I also need to be able to detect the scrolling. I need to know when the user has scrolled to the end if nothing else.

Is there a straight forward way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this isn't possible.

PDF in browser can only be read by an extension to the browser (e.g. Adobe Reader). Extensions have no public interface, so JavaScript can't do anything with it.